# can't add child block by reference in custom layout file (solved)

Tags: module, checkout, layout, template, magento-1

I'm trying to add new block to billing form in my custom layout file. I've debugged method `getFileLayoutUpdatesXm`l from `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update` and i see that my file is loaded. I have the following file

`newsletteronbillingform.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
            <block type="company_newsletteronbillingform/newsletter" name="checkout.onepage.billing.extra" template="newsletter/billingform/checkbox.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

When i add this directly in layout `checkout.xml` then works correctly

```
        <block type="checkout/onepage_login" name="checkout.onepage.login" as="login" template="checkout/onepage/login.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.onepage.login.before" as="login_before" translate="label">
                <label>Login/Registration Before</label>
                <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
                <block type="company_newsletteronbillingform/newsletter" name="checkout.onepage.billing.extra" template="newsletter/billingform/checkbox.phtml" />
            </block>

            <block type="cms/block" name="checkout_login_info_guest">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>checkout_login_info_guest</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="checkout_login_info_register">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>checkout_login_info_register</block_id></action>
            </block>

        </block>
```

What am I doing wrong?

[SOLUTION]

The reason was my oversight... :) I had doubly declared block "checkout.onepage.billing". After removing unnecessary second block it works correctly. Thx for help.

Comment: What if you add `as="checkout.onepage.billing.extra"` ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Here the code is mine. Add your own code as per need.

2.You can add your code in **local.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom"  template="checkout/custom.phtml" as="custom"></block>
    </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

3.Add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom');?>` in **billing.phtml**